# delete single row from group of unique - oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Considering the following scenario

```
GroupId Name
------------  
G1      A1  
G1      A2
G1      A3  
G2      B1  
G2      A2
```

, where `GroupId` and `Name` is always unique.

Now I need to change names to `C1` from all the groups and delete the remaining, so basically what I need is

```
GroupId Name
------------  
G1      C1  
G2      C1
```

How can I achieve this??

Comment: How about deleting all the groups and re-inserting the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete YOUR_TABLE_HERE
 where rowid NOT in (select max(rowid) from YOUR_TABLE_HERE group by groupId)

update YOUR_TABLE_HERE
   set name = 'C1'
```